# Why didn't this line of code update the object?

Tags: c#, .net, methods, struct, value-type

Given that there is a class called `Point` with a `float x` and  `float y` component.

```
class Point
{
    public double x;
    public double y;
    public Point(double x, double y)
    {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
    public Point()
    {
        x = y = 0;
    }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("({0:F2},{1:F2})", x, y);
    }
}
```

Why in the `mystery1` function didn't the point `p1` get updated to be (11.00, 11.00) since `p.x` is 11 from the first line?

```
{
    Point p1 = new Point(11, 22);
    Point p2 = p1;
    int n1 = 33;
    int n2 = n1;

    mystery1(p1, n1);
    Console.WriteLine("n1 = {0}, n2 = {1}", n1, n2);
    Console.WriteLine("p1 = {0}, p2 = {1}", p1, p2);

    mystery2(p2, n2);
    Console.WriteLine("n1 = {0}, n2 = {1}", n1, n2);
    Console.WriteLine("p1 = {0}, p2 = {1}", p1, p2);
}

static void mystery1(Point p, int n)
{
    n = (int)p.x;
    p = new Point(n, n);
}

static void mystery2(Point p, int n)
{
    p.x = 77;
    n = 88;
}
```

Comment: I think that changing addresses doesn't affect parameters.

Comment: You should read https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/0f66670z.aspx, in particular the link for `ref`- and `out`-parameter. In Short: all parameters in C# are passed by value, thus when you re-assign a reference-type changes to that variable (or more precise to the object this variable referes to) are not reflected in the original reference.

Comment: `static void mystery1(Point p, int n)
 {
 n = (int)p.x;
 p = new Point(n, n);
 }`  isn't it because you're using a void function? voids have no return value. So p1 won't be updated.

Comment: @Roy_Dorsthorst Even if the method wasn´t `void` the values were not updated.

Comment: @HimBromBeere but you could assign the function to p1 and have it return a Point right?

Comment: @Roy_Dorsthorst Sure, that´s possible.

Comment: do you refer to the `System.Point`-struct or do you have an own class called `Point`?

Comment: @HimBromBeere then why for mystery2 p2 got updated to (77.00, 11.00)?

Comment: @HimBromBeere I have an own class called Point

Comment: Please see the marked duplicate for the answer, in particular a discussion of how parameter passing in C# works. You are passing the `p1` reference by value, which means that when you assign a new value to the parameter `p`, it changes only the local parameter value, not the variable that was used to pass the original reference. If you want to change the original reference, you need to use `ref`.

Comment: see my answer for `mystery2`.

Comment: See [Why are mutable structs “evil”?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/441309/) _Edit:_ I retract this comment since this is about passing (references to) objects by value.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen: there are no structs here

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen Although your link is always good in this case it won´t apply because OP has an own class `Point`.

Answer (score 1):

Point is a value type. so when you call a method with a point as parameter, you have a new instance of the point in the method. So you are changing the values not on that instance that you have in the main method.

Have a look at the ref keyword: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0f66670z.aspx

Also at the moment you make a new instance with `new Point(n, n);`  you create even one more instance of point . 
You main method still points to the old object which is not getting changed.

Also I would recommend that you have a general look at the differences between value and complex types like here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/34yytbws(v=vs.100).aspx
or here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s1ax56ch.aspx

Comment: I also thought it was a struct from the framework until I saw the lowercase `x` member in the `mystery2` method.

Comment: I assumed it as a typo :-)

Comment: It's a mystery :|

Comment: _"Point is a value type"_ -- unlikely. The OP has stated it's his own class, and the code isn't consistent with any of the .NET `Point` types.

Comment: hmm maybe, @vso can you clearyfy where the point class comes from  ? Is it a class from you own ? Btw regardless making a new instance changes the instance from the one the  caller context uses.,

Comment: It's right there in the question: _"there is a **class** called Point"_.

Answer (score 1):

In C# all paramaters are passed by value, even references.

That means when you pass an instance of a class to a method you pass the reference of that instance *as value*. Imagine the reference (similar to a pointer) is simply the adress of an instance within the stack stored into a string (it´s not a string, but for simplicity let´s assume so). Now when you change that string what should happen to the outside? Nothing, because the string is just a value, it does not have anything to do with your actual referenced *instance*. This sounds weird, but that´s it. In your `msyter1`-method you simply *re*-assign this reference to a new instance, however you simply change the *value* of that reference, not the reference itself.

You could do this by passing the class by reference`:

```
static void mystery1(ref Point p, ref int n)
```

Now changes within the method are reflected to the outer of the method.

In `mystery2` there´s a difference and you won´t need the `ref`-keyword for your `Point`-class, because you´re not changing the reference itself but a property of the referenced *instance*. However this does not apply to the integer-argument which is of course a value-type and thus must be passed by `ref` to be updated outside your method also:

```
static void mystery2(Point p, ref int n)
```